# How to Store user profiles for a social network website

Tags: python, server-side-scripting

I may not use the correct terms ,please endure,
Let's say I wanted to create a mini social network website, how would I store and  handle the different profiles of the users on the server with python, would I use something like a dictionary?

Comment: I'm sure you are looking for the term `database`

Comment: I mean how to process a user profile